# Haskell encryption tips

Tags: haskell, caesar-cipher

I wrote a variation of the Caeser Cipher and would like some feedback.
Is it idiomatic? Can you generally see anything that can be improved?

Use example:

```
let e = enc "Hello World" "This is the key"
 in dec e "This is the key"
```

Instead of taking a single value as the offset, it takes a `String` as the key and uses each respective character from the key as the offset; wrapping when it reaches the upper/lower bound.

```
module Encryption where

import Data.Char

type Key = String
type Message = String
type Direction = (Int -> Int -> Int)

--Upper and lower ascii code bounds
upperBound = 127 ; lowerBound = 32

shift :: Char -> Char -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Char
shift char charoff dir = fix $ dir (ord char) (ord charoff)

fix :: Int -> Char
fix charcode
        | charcode > upperBound = chr $ (lowerBound - 1) + excessOf (upperBound + lowerBound)
        | charcode < lowerBound = chr $ (upperBound + 1) - excessOf (lowerBound - lowerBound)
        | otherwise = chr charcode
        where   excessOf boundry = abs(boundry - charcode)

alter :: Message -> Key -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Message
alter msg key dir = [(shift c k dir) | (c,k) <- zip msg (cycle key)]

enc msg key = alter msg key (+)
dec msg key = alter msg key (-)

--Basic Caeser Cipher
{-
alter :: Message -> Key -> Direction -> Message
alter m k dir = [chr $ dir (ord out) k | out <- m]

enc m k = alter m k (+)
dec m k = alter m k (-)
-}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Direction = (Int -> Int -> Int)
```

These parentheses are superfluous, though they don't really hurt if they help you to read the code.

```
upperBound = 127 ; lowerBound = 32
```

It's not very common to put definitions on the same line with `;`, particularly top-level definitions, so this made me double-take a bit. It makes it hard to find a particular definition by scanning the left column of the file.

It's a good idea to give all top-level definitions type signatures, as it helps to catch type errors earlier and makes it easier for someone reading the code.

Also, with numeric types, overloading in the `Num` class can often give surprising results, so explicitly stating that these are `Int` is a good idea.

```
shift :: Char -> Char -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Char
shift char charoff dir = fix $ dir (ord char) (ord charoff)
```

Consider putting the function argument first here. The function is more likely to be useful partially applied as `shift dir` than as `shift char`, and it also makes for a more intuitive type signature which correctly gives the sense that a function `Int -> Int -> Int` is being transformed into a function `Char -> Char -> Char`.

```
fix :: Int -> Char
```

As someone mentioned on your StackOverflow post, `fix` is a standard library name for something different, so best not to reuse it here.

```
| charcode > upperBound = chr $ (lowerBound - 1) + excessOf (upperBound + lowerBound)
| charcode < lowerBound = chr $ (upperBound + 1) - excessOf (lowerBound - lowerBound)
    where   excessOf boundry = abs(boundry - charcode)
```

I find it hard to understand these two cases. You could perhaps add comments to explain what they are doing. Also `lowerBound - lowerBound` is just `0` so what are you trying to do here? I presume the whole thing is about clamping to within the valid ASCII range but it's quite confusing.

In general I'd have expected a Caesar cipher just to work on letters, rather than the whole ASCII range, but that's a specification question really.

```
alter :: Message -> Key -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Message
alter msg key dir = [(shift c k dir) | (c,k) <- zip msg (cycle key)]
```

Again I would put the function as the first argument here. I would also put the `Key` as the second argument, because then you can partially apply it with a key to get a specialised encryption or decryption function. It might also make sense to have the key first and the function second.

```
enc msg key = alter msg key (+)
dec msg key = alter msg key (-)
```

As before, type signatures would help here. Also, if you do change the order of the arguments to `alter` above then this can be abbreviated as `enc = alter (+)` or `enc key` = `alter key (+)`, which is perhaps slightly more elegant.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. The fix function "wraps" characters falling outside of the upperBound/lowerBound range (s character with the code 128 becomes 32). I literally just scratched that part out on some paper. I'll see if I can either rework it so it's more intuitive, or figure out a descriptive comment. Thanks again! (I forgot to delete the SO post :/. I bet I have like 10 down votes by now.)

Comment: I'd have expected something with `mod` to do the wrapping - if you subtract `lowerBound`, use `mod n (upperBound - lowerBound)` to force it into the right range, then add back `lowerBound`, that should roughly cover it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into mod. I've never even heared of that function.

Comment: Oh, mod is just a synonym for rem? It looks like rem requires a lot more resources though.

Comment: They're not quite the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339719/when-is-the-difference-between-quotrem-and-divmod-useful - I think you need `mod` here. Apparently `rem` is more efficient but I doubt that's of any relevance in this code.